# Fetch latest matching string value

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a file which contains two values for `initial...` keyword. I want to grab the latest date for matching `initial...` string. After getting the date I also need to format the date by replacing `/` with `-`

```
---other data
    INFO   | abc 1    | 2018/01/04 20:04:35 | initial...

    INFO   | abc 1    | 2018/02/05 17:01:42 | INFO | new| InitialLauncher | c.t.s.s.setup.launch | initial...

---other data
```

In the above example, my output should be `2018-02-05`. Here, I am fetching the line which contains `initial...` value and only getting the line with latest date value. Then, I need to strip out the remaining string and fetch only the date value.

I am using the following `grep` but it is not yet as per the requirement.

```
grep -q -iF "initial..." /tmp/file.log
```

Comment: Is the data ever going to be stored with a newer date before an older date?  If not, you could just run the output from `grep` through `tail -n 1` to get the last row, and proceed from there.

Comment: We will always have newer date at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the knowledge that later dates appear later in the file, it's only necessary to print the date from the last line containing `initial...`.

First step (drop the `-q` from `grep` — you don't want it to be quiet):

```
grep -iF 'initial...' /tmp/file.log |
tail -n 1 |
sed -e 's/^[^|]*|[^|]*| *\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/' -e 's%/%-%g'
```

The (first) `s///` command matches a series of non-pipes followed by a pipe, another series of non-pipes followed by a pipe, a blank, then captures a series of non-blanks, and finally matches a blank and anything; it replaces all that with just the captured string, which is the date field after the second pipe on the input line.  The (second) `s%%%` command replaces slashes with dashes, using `%` to avoid the confusion that the equivalent `s/\//-/g` might engender, thereby reformatting the date in ISO 8601-style format.

But we can lose the `tail` with:

```
grep -iF 'initial...' /tmp/file.log |
sed -n -e '$ { s/^[^|]*|[^|]*| *\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/; s%/%-%gp; }'
```

The `-n` suppresses normal output; the `$` matches only the last line; the `p` after the second `s///` operation prints the result.

The case-insensitive fixed-pattern search is more conveniently written in `grep` than in `sed`.  Although it could be done in a single `sed` command, you have to work fairly hard, saving matching rows in the hold space, then swapping the hold and pattern space at the end, and doing the substitution and printing:

```
sed -n \
    -e '/[Ii][Nn][Ii][Tt][Ii][Aa][Ll]\.\.\./h' \
    -e '$ { x; s/^[^|]*|[^|]*| *\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/; s%/%-%gp; }' /tmp/file.log
```

Each of these produces the output 2018-02-05 on the sample data.  If fed an input with no `initial...` in it, they output nothing.

Answer (score 1):

something like this...

```
$ awk -F'|' '$NF~/initial\.\.\./ {if(max<$3) max=$3} 
             END  {gsub("/","-",max); 
                   split(max,dt," "); print dt[1]}' file
```

Comment: I am getting a null value. also tried replacing `initial` with `initial\.\.\.`

Comment: extra space in the FS.  Also sub->gsub try now.

Comment: Perhaps, split first and replace next, but too late for me to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Grep for only (`-o`) the string you want, sort it, and cut for the first word:

```
grep -o '2[0-9]\{3\}/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9] [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] .* | initial' file.txt | sort | cut -d' ' -f1 | tai -1
```

Comment: This is giving the first value `2018/01/04` However, the correct output should be `2018/02/05`. I also need to change the formatting and need output as `2018-02-05`

Comment: Just added another wildcard.  Didn't know what your target string was.  (Surely you could have gotten that far on your own, yes?)

Comment: I have done this one so far `grep -iF "initial..." file.txt | tail -n 1 | grep -o '2[0-9]\{3\}/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9] [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]'`

Comment: I lost my tail!  I feel like Eeyore.